# Pocket sphinx: Works on Device but not on emulator( virtual device)

Tags: android, android-studio, pocketsphinx, virtual-device-manager

I have downloaded a Pocket sphinx sample from : https://github.com/HelloSpoon/PocketSphinx_Sample.git , when i build this and install the .apk on my device, the application works ( mainly it proceeds further, and my words are recognised).
But, when i do the same on the emulator ( Android 5.1), the application Launches, but it does not recognise any words ( due to which its stuck in an infinite loop)

Can someone please help my understanding with this. Should i download any specific SDK (virtual device)

Comment: Emulator does not support recording audio in a proper audio format

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev , thanks for your response, is there a way to test this on emulator? for example can i install a plugin or make some changes in my code esp for the emulator?

Comment: No, you can buy a cheap android phone.

Comment: ok.. Thank You for your quick reply.